# Possible to escape or otherwise pass a value that includes / in Django URL

Tags: python, django, url

I'm building a tool using Django that works with the part numbers that my company uses, one set of part numbers includes /'s which I didn't realize when I set up the url to access the part summary.

Now when try to pass one of those part numbers it breaks things, is there a way to work around this? I'd like to avoid changing the part number or adding a unique id with no other meaning to the model.

an example part number that causes the problem is P-030-P-401/ND the url pattern is /parts/

Thanks in advance

Comment: not using `/` in a url as a path is kinda beating the purpose and routes

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, I was hoping my lack of experience/knowledge might be my savior! This is a fringe case that I missed when setting things up. I may have to bite the bullet and just add an autoID

Comment: maybe changing it to `P-030-P-401-ND` will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to change the route a bit, this is an option with just a few characters difference:

```
www.domain.com/parts/?part_id=P-030-P-401/ND
```

Example setup:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other paths here
    path("parts/", view_test),
]
```

views.py

```
def view_test(request):
    part_id = request.GET.get("part_id")
    return render(request, "parts/test.html", {"part_id": part_id})
```

test.html

```
{{part_id}}
```

Depending on browser settings maybe replace / with %2F, but it's working with the slash for me on Firefox.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I didn't even know that was possible!!